# How to GET values from Bootstrap Modal form?

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have used bootstrap modal form and i am trying to get the values using 'get' method this way but it is not working.
Can anyone tell me how to do using AJAX.
If it is possible to do without AJAX ,that would be very helpfull to me.

```
<div class='modal fade' id='editButtonModal' role='dialog'>
<div class='modal-dialog'>

  <div class='modal-content' >

      <div class='modal-header'>
        <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal'>&times;</button>
        <h4 style="color:red; text-align:center">My Article</h4>
      </div>

      <div class='modal-body'>

          <form role='form_edit' action="addArticle.php" method="get">

              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="Title" >Title</label>
                <input type="text"  class="form-control" id="titleId" name='tit' placeholder="Enter the title of the article">
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="ArticleContent">Your Thoughts!</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" rows='10' id="artcleContentId"></textarea>
              </div>

              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-success btn-block" >Submit</button>

          </form>

      </div>

  </div>

</div>
</div>
```

Php file:

```
echo "hello world"
echo $_GET['tit']
```

Comment: Don't forget semicolons in php...

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: It is not printing the value entered in the text box when submit is pressed

Comment: @NETCreatorHosting-WebDesign Thank you soo much man!! I Was strugling with this since 3 hours and its all because of a semicolon!!

Comment: You are always welcome. We are happy to help you. I added this as an answer below.

Comment: Just for the record, running your PHP code with terminal/console is almost obligated for the debug purposes. The parser kicks in and shows the cause of error within the range. Always helped me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is an error in your PHP file. You lost semicolons.

It should be:

```
echo "hello world";
echo $_GET['tit'];
```